# Why IBM Bluemix DevOps pipeline stage using .bluemix/pipeline.yml file's stage instructions added only when we deploy a cloned project?

Tags: git, ibm-cloud, pipeline, devops

When we check in the code (.bluemix/pipeline.yml) to the IBM JazzHub project on Bluemix, it doesn't get added automatically to the pipeline as stages (as mentioned in the pipeline.yml) to the parent project. Any project that gets cloned through the "Deploy to bluemix" is seen with the added pipeline instructions (fetched from yml) without manually adding it.

How can I add the pipeline instructions to the parent project itself with something like import, or through command line or thru just checking in the pipeline.yml?

Answer (score 0):

The Deploy to Bluemix capability is the only way to generate a Bluemix project's pipeline from a YAML file at this time.